# How to remove text from inbound SMS body of twilio

Tags: twilio

In my Twilio studio flow I have a set variables widget setup that looks at the inbound sms body and sets it to a variable called "textbody".  This all works appropriately, but I am trying to take that dynamic text and remove certain words using the [Liquid Templating Language](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language#expressions-and-variables)

I have tried different syntax, but have not been able to get it to work:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

While I am using a different function than in the original question, the syntax for working with dynamic variables is as follows:
{{trigger.message.Body | split:"." |  first}}

Comment: How can I remove Digits from a string or vice versa, Remove Non-Digit Characters from a string? so if the message body is 'Hello 123' The Variable will be '123'?